# install windows Postgres logical decoding plugin

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Recently I was working on a project where I am supposed to capture data change on a postgres db to update a cache.

After some search i found that i could use Embedded-Debezium to detect all changes on the data base.

In order to ensure the communication between debezium and postgres db , I need to install a logical decoder output plugin to deliver data as Protocol Buffers 
[postgres-decoderbufs-output-plugin](https://github.com/debezium/postgres-decoderbufs)

The link above showing how to install the plugin into Pg installed on a linux distributions..

I wonder how to install it for PG installed on a windows machine?

Is there any other options to integrate debezium with PG wihtout using this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Postgres Debezium logical decoding plugin is not available for windows is not available yet you have to build it by your self.